# How can I create HTML email drafts in Gmail using Python?

Tags: python, email, gmail, html-email, imaplib

I can successfully create plaintext email drafts in Gmail using this snippet:

```
from email.message import Message
import imaplib
import time

message = Message()

    # Create message
    message["To"] = "john.doe@gmail.com"
    message["Subject"] = "Subject line"
    message.set_payload("This is the email <a href=#>body</a>")
    utf8_message = str(message).encode("utf-8")

    # Send message
    status, data = imap_ssl.append('"[Google Mail]/Drafts"', "", imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), utf8_message)
```

However, it displays as:

`This is the email <a href=#>body</a>`

Is there a way to get it to display as this?

> This is the email [body](https://#)

I've tried playing with MIMEText, which I can successfully use to send HTML emails via `smtplib`, but I'm not sure if it's possible with `imaplib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a content-type header

```
    message["Content-Type"] = "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
```